# How do I populate a field with data

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, parallel-processing

I'm hoping I could get this issue resolved here. I'm trying to automate a process that involves selecting options from a list of options (by looping through each) and saving these options, simply by clicking the save button.

What I've tried so far is by using selenium to locate the tags and clicking on it using the click function. This works fine but the test site crashes on Heroku and other hosting sites I've tried due to memory issue, even on Digital Ocean.

I know I can automate this bit using Javascript but I really do not know how to search for the right article [I do know it involves using Fetch. I think] I have managed to get the API route feeding the site its data for this method.

My code so far (abridged):

```
for task in tasks:
     elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input.searchInput.keyboardInput')
                elem.click() #needs to be clicked on first 
                elem.send_keys(task)
                elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

     #handle elem
#click on save button
```

I really just need to populate the task table with selected tasks and then save, without having to open multiple chrome instances by selenium, which is the cause of memory overload.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to automate actions on another webpage? Can you share the webpage you are trying to do this on?

Comment: Bet365. I have a machine learning model to predict matches, and this is just selecting the match from a list of matches and then selecting the predicted outcome on the website, for each match before booking it.